# Adding spacing between rows of Bootstrap buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a number of buttons inside of a Bootstrap button toolbar that is breaking over to a new row. This is fine, but there is no spacing between these rows, how can I add that without explicitly creating new rows ahead of time?

[Codepen Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MrgVxx)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably add a little bootstrap customization:

```
.btn-toolbar .btn-default {
  margin-top: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add custom css:

```css
.btn{
  margin:3px !important;
}
```

Comment: Why `!important` ? I avoid it as much as possible. Adding custom css after the bootstrap library, and using the cascade (and higher specificity) it should be possible to avoid. With just .btn it will also affect every button of the user's site.

Comment: it not important.

Answer (score 1):

```
.btn-toolbar>.btn{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

The above code will make equal spacing around all the buttons.Also let me know if any issue.

Even if you create a whole row consist of all buttons then according to your layout you can increase the margin bottom so that it will create enough space for your layout.